# Prove that $e^{-T}=(e^T)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-transformations, exponentiation

Should I use the theorem: $S,T$ linear transformations in $\mathbb R^n$ such that $ST=TS$ $\implies e^{S+T}=e^Se^T$ to prove $e^{-T}=(e^T)^{-1}$?

My professor suggested to apply the mentioned theorem, but I don't see how to apply it.

Can someone give a hint?

Thnks in advance.

Comment: $T$ and $-T$ commute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Randall pointed out, $T$ and $-T$ commute, that is $T(-T)=-T(T)$.

Using your theorem with these particular transformation yields to $e^{-T+T}=e^{T}e^{-T}$.

But $e^{-T+T}=1$  thus $e^{T}e^{-T}=1$, thus $e^{T}=\frac 1{e^{T}}=(e^{T})^{-1}.$